# Expected value of conditional expected value

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

We know that $E[E[X|Y]] = E[X]$, does this hold for all RVs $Y$ or is this is just if $X,Y$ are independent. In particular does this hold for $E[X | X+Y]$ where $X,Y$ are independent?

I'm wondering because in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.01682.pdf#page=59 the author says that for $E[Xg(Y)] / E[g(Y)^2]$ the cauchy schwarz inequality says that the optimal function $g^*(Y) = E[X|Y]$ where $Y = X+G$ with $G \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$. Is this because $E[XE[X|Y]] = E[XX] = E[E[X|Y]E[X|Y]]$ thus $E[Xg^*(Y)] / E[g^*(Y)^2] = E[g^*(Y)^2]$?

Comment: It always holds, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then you get the stronger statement $\mathbb E[X|Y]=\mathbb E[X]$.

Comment: By the way, $\mathbb E[X\mathbb E[X|Y]]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X|Y]^2]$ is correct but $\mathbb E[X\mathbb E[X|Y]]\neq \mathbb E[X]^2$.

Comment: Is there any constraint on $g(Y)$ ?

Comment: It has to be lipschitz differentialable with some other properties which are not important for this I think, thanks for your help!

Comment: is it true that $E[XE[X|Y]] = E[X^2]$?

Comment: That would be true if $X=\mathbb E[X|Y]$, for instance if $X$ is a function of $Y$.

Comment: Is it possible that there is a missing square, something like $\frac{\mathbb E[Xg(Y)]^2}{\mathbb E[g(Y)^2]}$ ? And in what sense do you mean optimal ? maximizing with respet to $g$ ?